# Can my Mac be affected without running the malware?

Tags: malware, virus, macos, infection-vector

Can my Mac be affected by malware without running it?  For instance, if I download a random file, but don't open it, can it infect my computer?

Comment: Take a look at this fake AV that can infect you by simply clicking an image on Google images https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L6cvUY4CGp0 You can get infected without downloading anything

Answer (score 2):

Potentially yes.

Examples:

You download a picture. While you never open the picture, the OS may generate thumbnails for it. If there's a bug (vulnerability) in the thumbnail generator, it may result in code execution.

You download a document. While you never open the document yourself, the Search Indexer reads the file to speed up finding documents. If there's a bug in the Search Indexer, it may result in code execution.

Worst example: you download an executable but never run it. The virus scanner reads the file to check it for viruses. If the virus scanner has a vulnerability, it might even be the virus scanner that finally causes the infection.

That said, it is not a good idea to uninstall a virus scanner for that reason. Chances are quite low for this to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Malicious code needs to be run by your computer, but sometimes you don't have to open the file in order for it to be run. Some browsers can be infected by drive-by-downloads, which infect your machine simply by browsing.

But, for your specific question, if you downloaded a file, it will not infect you until you open/run it.

Comment: Good to know! Thanks. Sorry for the noob question.